# SEAndroid error while restore data

Tags: backup, selinux

I was wrote a backuprestore APP for backup restore  app data ,let's call it Application A ,  and  there is a Application I want to backhandrestore ,let's call it Application B.

I use A to backup the B's data in format .tar,and restore it for B.

Problem is normally the data of B's SEAndroid label is u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 , but A is a system app ,so when the data restore to B ,the label was changing to u:object_r:app_data_file:s0, so application b will crash while open because permission denial.